# What is the difference between iTerm2 and xTerm keys?

Tags: tmux

Recently, I started to use Tmux, but I'm so curious why we should add this configuration at the beginning of `.tmux.conf`.

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

What is the difference between `xterm` keys and `iterm2` keys? And if I don't set like this, what will happen?